# How can tackle this question related to isomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

**The question is** :

In the group $(\mathbb Z_{2})^3$,find the number of subgroups isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_{2})^2$.

I find difficulty in working out this question.Please help me.

**EDIT** :

I think it is possible in ${7\choose 2}$ ways.Because suppose we take $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ as any three elements then the fourth element should be $(1,1,0)$.Isn't it?Hence we only have to take any two elements from the remaining $7$ by keeping identity element fixed, which is possible in only ${7 \choose 2}$ ways.Please verify whether it is correct or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Can you name any subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2^2$? Please edit the post to include this information.

Comment: Is it $K_4$,the Klein's-4-group?

Comment: Yes, $K_4$ and $\mathbb Z_2^2$ are isomorphic.

Comment: I think it is possible in $7_{C_{2}}$ ways.Isn't it?

Comment: You should edit the OP with that statement, as well as an explication of where that number came from, so that people can evaluate your work and suggest improvements without having to read the comments.

Comment: I assume you mean "7 choose 2" by that, which I'm more used to seeing as ${7 choose 2}$ or $_7C_2$. Please confirm that my edit is correct, or define the notation $7_{C_2}$

Comment: You have counted each subgroup three times, once for each pair of nonzero vectors in the subgroup.